# .hover and jquery on ipad/phone

Tags: jquery, ios

I have written some script that when a user hovers over some text in a marquee it will pause the marquee and then when the users mouse goes off the text it will start back up. Since ipads and phones don't use the mouse I am having an issue restarting the marquee perfectly on them. My initial thoughts were to create a delay after the hover and then restart the scrolling after that delay. It works partly but not fully as the marquee will start and stop over and over after the link is clicked on an phone and ipad.

So how do I get around this problem?

```
$('marquee p').hover(
    function(){//When mouse hovers over
        $('marquee').attr({scrollamount:0});

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('marquee').attr({scrollamount:2});
            ;},3000);
    },
    function(){//When mouse doesn't hover over
        $('marquee').attr({scrollamount:2});
    }
);
```

Comment: marquee tag. see [w3c](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee)

Comment: And if I switch to a jquery scroller do you think my issue will be resolved or were you just pointing to the fact that the article you linked to stated don't use the marquee tag?